# How to get value of node with refs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is the following code:

```
      <Field
        ref={node => {
          this.field = node;
        }}
      />
```

and then in some function:

```
console.log(this.field.inputRef.value);
```

tell me that

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Why? How can I tell value of node with refs in React? Thanks!

Comment: What's a `<TextField>`? Does it have an `inputRef`?

Comment: Are you able to access & mod the TextField code? Otherwise there must be a documentation for the `TextField` component, where you can do it with props usually..

Answer (score 0):

`inputRef` looks like an extraneous property. Probably you stepped into a typo of:

```
console.log(this.field.value);
```

Comment: That depends on how `<TextField>` works, which we don't know.